# How do I save work in progress without using git-stash?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-stash, git-reset

I have a git directory with this situation:

```
ProgSoul@PROGSOUL-LENOVO:~/esercizio3_2$ git status
Sul branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   A

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   A

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        B
```

In this situation I have:

- there is a file named A in the index with a string "AA" inside it
- I modified the file A with "AAA" inside it but I didn't add this change on the stage. So in the working directory I have A with a string "AAA" inside it
- an untracked empty file B

My teacher wants me to temporarily suspend my work, create a BUGFIX file, commit it and restore my previous situation.

I achieved it through these commands:

```
git stash --include-untracked
touch BUGFIX
git add BUGFIX
git commit -m "Aggiunto file BUGFIX"
git stash pop --index
```

With these commands I saved my initial situation and restored it once my fix has been commited.
My teacher also asked me to reach this goal without using git-stash.

I followed the help in the stash documentation:

```
git checkout -b WIP
git commit -a -m "WIP"
git checkout master
touch BUGFIX
git add BUGFIX
git commit -a -m "BUGFIX"
git checkout WIP
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

With git reset --soft I restored the index but the changes not staged for commit have been lost.

With git reset --mixed I restored the changes not staged for commit but the index has been lost.

How can I restore the same initial situation once I commit the fix without using git stash?

Comment: I don't see the value in this question. Why would you deliberately try to work around an already existing nice and easy solution? This is only relevant for your class so you better just ask your teacher how to solve this "problem".

Comment: I can't ask the solution to my teacher, so I need a workaround. Maybe it's not useful for you but it's useful for me.

Comment: Are you allowed to commit your changes and create the bugfix on another branch?

Comment: Yes, I can. I haven't any restrictions about how to achieve the result.

Comment: After you run `git commit -a -m "WIP"` the file `A` is committed.  That appears to be one of the reasons why your working tree doesn't look the same in the end.

Comment: Clone the original repository to a new directory.  Make your bugfix/commit/push.  Go back to original directory.  Pull down changes.  Continue.

Comment: I think that's what branches are for. Git is not tvs, stop working on one branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to every answer I received. I achieved two possible solutions:

```
git worktree add -b BUGFIX ../bugfix_temp master
pushd ../bugfix_temp
touch BUGFIX
git add BUGFIX
git commit -a -m "emergency BUGFIX"
popd
rm -rf ../bugfix_temp
git worktree prune
```

OR

```
touch BUGFIX
git add BUGFIX
git commit --only BUGFIX -m "emergency BUGFIX"
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's try it this way:

- Q: How can you save something in Git?
- A: Commit it.
- Q: What about `git stash`, it seems to save things, how does it manage that?
- A: It commits.
- Q: But it doesn't put any commits on my branch.<sup>1</sup>
- A: They're on the special "stash" thing, which is not a branch.  But they're still commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is, technically, not a question. :-)

---

#### If you want to save something in Git, commit it

This is the Git bottom line, as it were: a commit saves things.  Otherwise all you have is stuff in your work-tree, and stuff in your index (staging-area).  The staging-area stuff becomes permanent when you run `git commit`.  The work-tree stuff is *never* permanent: you have to copy it to the staging area and then commit it.

This is what `git stash` does.  It actually makes *two* commits, one for the current index, and one for the work-tree.<sup>2</sup>  It just makes them both on something other than a branch, using the name `stash` to find them instead.

There's nothing stopping you from making your own commits, though.  It's just a bit of a pain to make two or more commits and then have to undo them, which is why `git stash` exists.

---

<sup>2</sup>When you use `--include-untracked` as you did, it actually makes *three* commits: one for the index, a second for the work-tree, and a third one for the untracked files.  That third commit is extra-tricky, both to make and to restore.  The stash script uses a temporary index rather than trying to do the work in the main index.

---

#### You can always use another clone

Each Git repository is, in general, independent of all other Git repositories, but can peer with any related Git repository.  So you can clone one repository to another, and thereby get another work-tree where you can do work.  This work-tree also comes with its own (separate) index / staging-area.

If you make the clone locally, on your local file system, Git is often able to avoid a lot of repository-file copying.  So while this might seem expensive, it's usually not that bad.  The main problem is that you now have two repositories to remember to commit-to, and you must fetch and/or push between them and/or whatever upstream you originally cloned from.

#### For quick side work, `git worktree add` (2.5 and newer only)

Before Git 2.5 there was a "contributed" script to make alternate work-trees.  As of 2.5 it became officially supported, though there were some important bug fixes since then (and even now it has some rough edges).  You can now run `git worktree add` to create a new worktree that will use a *different* branch, but share the underlying repository.

No two work-trees that share one underlying repository may use the same branch.  (This is because of the way Git stores its idea of the "current branch" and "current commit", and the way Git advances the current branch when you make a *new* commit.)  If your goal, however, is to make a fix in some *other* branch than the one you are working on now, this is just what you need anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it's a useful answer. I posted the complete solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you have bunch of changes in a file which you would like to save but not yet commit, then one option would be taking a diff of your changes and save that diff to a file and store diff in some other location.

```
git diff changedfile > ~/diff_of_an_idea.diff
git restore changedfile # back to original
```

then sometime later when you want to include diff

```
git apply ~/diff_of_an_idea.diff
git add & git commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Git's got a little-known feature just for this, built in.

```
echo fix fix >> BUGFIX
git add BUGFIX
git commit BUGFIX
```

... and if `BUGFIX` were already tracked, you wouldn't even need the `git add`, it'd do that for you.  See point 3 of [the `git commit` description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_description):

> listing files as arguments to the commit command (without --interactive or --patch switch), in which case the commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead record the current content of the listed files (which must already be known to Git);

and although the description doesn't say it, the current contents are added to the index as well as the commit.

Comment: The one issue with this is that without `--only` or command line file arguments, you'll also commit files that are currently staged, so that's easy to do by mistake.  (With command line arguments, to also include staged files, use `--include`.)  This is a handy thing to know for committing just one file, though. [SIde note: `--only` is the default if there are command line file arguments, and `--only` *without* such arguments makes no sense, so why does `--only` exist? :-) ]

Comment: But the backout for a mistaken commit is cheap and easy, `git reset @^; git read-tree @{1}`.

Comment: Hm.  Oh, and I haven't checked recently—Git has changed since I experimented a while ago—but `git commit --only foo` wound up extracting the committed work-tree `foo` from `HEAD` into the index even if there was a modified version of `foo` staged, hence destroying the carefully-staged version. So there was one other danger here I'd forgotten, but have now remembered.

Comment: Well, its behavior gets exactly the same result as the stashing method, since stash pop merges.

Comment: Yes, unless you use `git stash pop --index` or `git stash apply --index` (or `git stash branch`, which uses `pop --index`). None of these are an issue for a *new* file of course.